# request cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, arrays

The problem I have is with the request when splitting. It says request cannot be resolved to a type.

```
public class RequestHandler implements IRequestHandler {

        private static final String NO_IMPL_GET_1_0 = "HTTP/1.0 501 GET Not Implemented\r\n\r\n";
        private static final String NO_IMPL_HEAD_1_0 = "HTTP/1.0 501 HEAD Not Implemented\r\n\r\n";
        private static final String NO_IMPL_POST_1_0 = "HTTP/1.0 501 POST Not Implemented\r\n\r\n";
        private static final String BAD_REQUEST_1_0 = "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n";
        private static final String BAD_REQUEST_0_9 = "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n";

        @Override
        public byte[] processRequest(byte[] request) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String request1 = new String(request1);
                String[] array1 = new request.split(" "); //Problem here with the request
                String resp = null;

                if (array1.length == 3 && array1[0].equals("GET")) {
                        resp = RequestHandler.NO_IMPL_GET_1_0;
                        System.out.println(resp);
                } else if (array1[0].equals("HEAD")) {
                        resp = RequestHandler.NO_IMPL_HEAD_1_0;
                        System.out.println(resp);
                } else if (array1[0].equals("POST")) {
                        resp = RequestHandler.NO_IMPL_POST_1_0;
                        System.out.println(resp);
                } else {
                        resp = RequestHandler.BAD_REQUEST_1_0;
                        System.out.println(resp);
                }

                if (array1.length == 2 && array1[0].equals("GET")) {
                        resp = RequestHandler.BAD_REQUEST_0_9;
                        System.out.println(resp);

                }
        }
}
```

Comment: just `request.split`, not `new request.split`

Comment: And you don't split an array.

Comment: It gives me another error: Cannot invoke split(String) on the array type byte[]

Comment: Because you want to split the string, not the array.

Comment: So how shall I do it? Thanks

Comment: I am trying to implement a request handler for http 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These line contain several problems:

```
public byte[] processRequest(byte[] request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String request1 = new String(request1);
    String[] array1 = new request.split(" ");
```

1. You're trying to intialize the variable `request1` with a new `String` instance of `request1`. But how can you "read" from `request1` (to create the new String) if it isn't created yet?
2. The `new` statement is used to create "new" instances of a certain class, like `new String(...)`. You've called it with a variable, instead of a class name. That can't work.
3. You're trying to split a `byte` array. That doesn't work, because there is no method defined for this data type.

I guess your main problem here, is the bad variable naming. You have `request` and `request1` and you had switched them in your code. You used `request1` where you should use `request` and used `request` where you should use `request1` instead.

Try to find better names for your variables, so you know what they contain and how they should be treated/used:

```
public byte[] processRequest(byte[] request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String requestAsString = new String(request);
    String[] requestParts = requestAsString.split(" ");
```

These may not be the best names, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works now, the only bit left was the inclusion of 'return request'.

Comment: @PDewan Glad it helped. Always try to use meaningful variable and method names. :)

Answer (score -2):

Replace `String[] array1 = new request.split(" ");`
with
`String[] array1 = request.split(" ");`
That's it.

Comment: What does splitting a byte array on space mean?

Comment: It gives me another error: Cannot invoke split(String) on the array type byte[]